# jQuery selection. Find element after another

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
<li>
  <select id="foo"></select>
</li>
<li>
  <select id="bar"></select>
</li>
<li>
  <select id="baz"></select>
</li>

var select_after = function(src){
   //How get all select elements after the one specified as argument ?
}
```

How write this method ?

```
select_after($("#foo"))
```

should return #bar and #baz elements in array

```
select_after($("#bar"))
```

should return #baz element in array

```
select_after($("#baz"))
```

should return empty array

How should I write this method ?

Comment: [Quite related answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29084305/274502)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a simple single-liner you could use the following chain:

```
$("#foo").parent().nextAll().children("select");
```

The code above will first select the parent, which is the `li` element, then select all of the siblings that comes after it, and finally return the `select` elements within. As seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/WZxRP/).

However, this method is both bulky and slow since you are walking the DOM. Another method that I rather use because it is way faster when working with a larger set of elements,

Preselection of all `select` elements, then create an object with references of the id to the index by looping them. Now you can just splice the jQuery object to get the elements that comes after (or before).

```
// Preselect select elements
var selects = $("ul > li > select"),
    // Prepare empty object to hold index reference
    idx = {};

// Loop through the select elements and build index reference
selects.each(function(i){idx[this.id] = i;});

// Get select elements after #foo
console.log(selects.slice(idx.foo+1));

// Get select elements before #baz
console.log(selects.slice(0, idx.baz));
```

Check out the above method in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/WZxRP/2/).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Could you provide a fiddle that does?

Comment: @JohnP, sorry. Made a small mistake ;) updated answer accordingly and with fiddle to boot.

Comment: @JohnP, goodie! I'm still not very fond of this method. It feels like a very bulky chain...

@Town, hehe I try, but my brain have its short-circuits as well ;)

Comment: @bashman and @JohnP, updated answer with another (preferred) method!